# XML response filled with questionmarks

Tags: xml

I try to fetch some data by requesting a link to a xml feed.
What I get is data filled with questionmarks. How do I fix it? I have a screenshot of the data I get

[image]

Comment: How do you fetch it? seems you are not sending the right headers. What you see is probably a compressed response in plain text.

Comment: The screenshot is just a request using Postman. Actually the url I'm using, is a zipped xml, used to download. But can I extract it without downloading it? Its supposed to

Comment: yeah, I guess so. You can do that in one step with Bash.

Comment: Can you give me an example? Haven't worked with bash. I'm using javascript

Comment: `wget http://example.com/xml.zip -O tmp.zip; unzip -p tmp.xml | less`